# I want to bridge my ethernet to my wifi, but there is no ethernet port listed. What can I do?

Tags: drivers, ethernet, network-bridge

Under Network Connections, I have no "Wired Connection"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ifconfig -a`, after that youu can see ethernet port. Now we need to bridge

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
ifconfig ath0 0.0.0.0   #ath0 is wireless interface name
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 ath0
ifconfig ath0 up
ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig br0 up
```

Now you can access internet.